# How to get back to previous numbering value and indentation after promoting a level?

Tags: asciidoc, asciidoctor, asciidoctor-pdf

This:

```
. Level one.
.. Level two.
   How do I get back to level 1?
. Back to level one.
```

will result in this:

```
1. Level one.
   a. Level two. How do I get back to level 1?
2. Back to level one.
```

But how can I accomplish this:

```
1. Level one.
   a. Level two.
   How do I get back to level 1?
2. Back to level one.
```

So that "`How do I get back to level 1?`" is indented the same as `Level one.`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following should work:

```
. Level one.                                                                                   
.. Level two.                                                                                  

+                                                                                              
How do I get back to level 1?                                                                  

. Back to level one.
```

Note the blank line and the lone `+`: these shift the list level one back, whilst attaching the next paragraph to the previous item.

See [the AsciiDoc writer's guide on asciidoctor.org, about attaching to an ancestor list](https://asciidoctor.org/docs/asciidoc-writers-guide/#attaching-to-an-ancestor-list):

> You may find that you need to attach block content to a parent list
>   item instead of the current one. In other words, you want to attach
>   the block content to the parent list item so it becomes a sibling of
>   the child list. To do this, you add a blank line before the list
>   continuation. The blank line signals to the list continuation to move
>   out of the current list so it attaches the block to the last item of
>   the parent list.
>
> ...
>
> Each blank line that precedes the list continuation signals a move up
>   one level of nesting.

The above renders in my browser as

```
1. Level one.

   a. Level two.

  How do I get back to level 1?

2. Back to level one.
```

and in HTML as

```
<div class="olist arabic">
<ol class="arabic">
<li>
<p>Level one.</p>
<div class="olist loweralpha">
<ol class="loweralpha" type="a">
<li>
<p>Level two.</p>
</li>
</ol>
</div>
<div class="paragraph">
<p>How do I get back to level 1?</p>
</div>
</li>
<li>
<p>Back to level one.</p>
</li>
</ol>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

One benefit of asciidoctor are the limitations in layouting the text. Best solution would be to accept the layout as it is, because it renders correctly from a semantic sence. I guess you have good reasons to do it differently, maybe the following solution helps:

```
. Level one.
.. Level two.

How do I get back to level 1?

[start=2]
. Back to level one.
```

The draw-back of this solution is, that "How to I get back to level1" is formatted as normal text. [Asciidoctor Documentation](http://asciidoctor.org/docs/asciidoc-writers-guide/#ordering-the-things) contains some examples.

Comment: Yes, there is this option... but as you expressed between the lines, this is not a desired solution as the indentation is eliminated. Thank you for your good will though ☺

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
. Level one.
.. Level two.
+
How do I get back to level 1?
. Back to level one.
```

http://asciidoctor.org/docs/user-manual/#list-continuation

Comment: It doesn't return to level 1, it stays in level two, just in a new line.

Comment: Ah, got it, you want to just insert a Level 2 item/list into your Level 1 item and afterwards continue with the same Level 1 item... Maybe some experiments with blocks or with passthrough elements? I don't know of an element to indicate the _end_ of a Level 2 item. (Obviously an unusual case, sorry.)